# java.lang.NumberFormatException for large numbers

Tags: java

In the code below, I am getting a java.lang.NumberFormatException when entering large numbers ~1000000000. The error occurs on the second-last line -\

```
int integer = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
```

It should work in theory since Integer type supports till 2^32-1 but it doesn't

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
//accept user input and convert into double
String s = user_input.next();
double number = Double.parseDouble(s);
System.out.println(number);

String answer = "";

//Split the entered number into Integer and Decimal parts
String split[] = Double.toString(number).split("\\.");
int integer = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
```

Comment: did you check what `split` contains? probably `split[0]` contains nothing or contains the '.'

Comment: A large number is toString'ed in an e-notation. That's where it fails for you. You should just have printed the result of  `Double.toString` and you'd save yourself from typing this question.

Comment: Actually, 2^31 - 1 -- remember that Java types are signed. Are you sure the error occurs when parsing the integer part, and not the decimal part? Otherwise I can't see how it'd bail if the input is significantly less than 2 billion

Comment: Maybe provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which illustrates the problem.  E.g., start with `String s = 'some value that shows the problem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably because of the representation of a large double which will be in scientific notation:

```
1.0E9
```

This will mean that the split is failing, try printing out the value of the string you are parsing.

When you call toString on a double, the format used can vary, try using [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) instead:

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.00000000").format(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29), this occurs when "the string cannot be parsed as an integer".  Among other reasons, this would be the case if the value exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

So things larger than about 2 billion or smaller than negative 2 billion (2^31-1, and -2^31 to be exact). Your example, -1,000,000,000 (commas added) should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that huge numbers are represented like `1.E9` or similar. So, when you do the split for getting the `integer` value you will get `1` and for the `decimal` part you will get `E9` which is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse the number 1000000000 is valid but I suspect the character ~ causes the NumberFormatException. You should be careful anyway with this code because a number like this 1.34184E24 is a valid Double in java but parsing the decimal split using Integer.parseInt will also result in NumberFormatException because there is an E.